# Thumbnail images on main page are showing too big in blogger

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails, blogger

I'm using a template named as GoGreen (By Templateism) on blogger. I've edited its color and other things.

The problem I am facing is, that when I make a post on it, and place a image (for example I choose an image which is not very big) at the top of the page.

It looks good, but the same image on main page becomes big and blurry. I try to fix but failed.

Comment: Walaikumasalam. By inspecting your element, it appears that all your images will be be changed to 320 x 195px. You can either edit the class called `postthumb`, or you can upload bigger images to your actual post (so that they don't become too pixelized). Let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried editing the postthumb image width and height. But nothing happened. Let me try by posting big images.

Comment: @9997 I tried by making a size of image in a post about (How to get payoneer mastercard) big, But still no change :(

Comment: What size is your original image?

Comment: the size of original image is normal, after you said that i should try making it big. So i increased the size by going in the post and the i chagned the size to 400 width and 200 height You can see the post [link](http://www.pkgeek.com/2014/03/how-to-get-payoneer-mastercard.html)

Comment: Try your best to make them 320 x 195px, or have the same proportions. I really can't think of another way to ensure that they don't get cut off.

Comment: You can measure it by using a Pixel ruler. The image that I am using in the post, I updated it to LARGE from Normal and the LARGE Size is (400x200)

Comment: Side note, relevant code should be posted.  If that link goes down, as all sites do eventually, this question loses all meaning for future readers.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Actually the code which is for that thumbnail is just :| . I tried putting small width and height but it doesn't do anything. BTW i don't think that site will go down because It's is on blogger (Google)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link on which this question is wholly dependent has now died.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson: yep, link has died here. I'm voting to close.